# How to install `git-completion.zsh` with `zi` plugin manager

Tags: git, zsh, zsh-completion

How can I install [`git-completion.zsh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh) with `zi` plugin manager?